# illegal_argument_exception: index.lifecycle.rollover_alias [elbtest] does not point to index [elb-test-2023.06.27]

Tags: elasticsearch

I have set up a server with Kibana + Elasticsearch + Logstash

Idea is to have logstash fetch logs from Amazon ELB and send them to elasticsearch so that they are viewable in Kibana. It works great for a couple of months, however the index lifecycle policy I set up have an error so older indexes does not get deleted and disk gets full.

Here is the logstash output filter:

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "elb-prod-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"
  }
}
```

I use the lifecycle policy called 30-days-default

But I still get this error and old indexes are not deleted:

```
illegal_argument_exception: index.lifecycle.rollover_alias [elbprod] does not point to index [elb-prod-2023-09-18]
```

Any ideas?